# Find condition for the number $A=\frac{n^a}{a}+\frac{n^b}{b}+\frac{n^c}{c }$ be prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find condition for the number $A=\frac{n^a}{a}+\frac{n^b}{b}+\frac{n^c}{c }$ be prime.

Solution:

Suppose n is prime to numbers a, b and c, then we have:

$n^a≡1 \mod (abc)= k (abc) +1$

⇒ $\frac{n^a}{a}=k_1 (bc)+\frac{1}{a}$

$\frac{n^b}{b}=k_2 (ac)+\frac{1}{b}$

$\frac{n^c}{c}=k_3 (ab)+\frac{1}{c}$

$A=\frac{n^a}{a}+\frac{n^b}{b}+\frac{n^c}{c }=k_1(bc)+k_2(ac)+k_3(ab)+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

Therefore we must have:

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=B$; $B$, integer.

So values for a, b and c are limited to $(a, b ,c)= (3, 3, 3)$ and $(2, 3, 6)$. So this statement can only be true for these numbers and $n=6k+1$.

Generally the numbers like $A=\frac{n^a}{a}+\frac{n^b}{b}+\frac{n^c}{c } + . . .$  can be infinite, because there can always be solutions for sums of  following type:

$B=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+ . . .= 1$

That is if B is integer there can be an integer like A.For A with three terms for $a=h=c=1$, $A=3$ which is prime and seems to be an exception, because number A seems to be normally composite; for example for ($ a=2, b=3, c=6$), we get $A=403=13\times 31$. I could not prove this analytically. Any Idea for proving analytically that numbers like A can be prime in following conditions?

$A=a.b.c...+1$

$B=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+ . . .$; $B ∈ \mathbb Z$

Comment: What for $(1,1,1)$?

Comment: @Mateo,Yes can be. I mean n can not be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly it is to find all integer solutions of 
$$\frac{n^a}{a}+\frac{n^b}{b}+\frac{n^c}{c } + . . .=p$$
where $p$ is prime and $n$ is prime to $a,b,c,...$. Without loss of generality we can suppose $a\le b\le c\le ...$

Multiplying out we have $$n^abc...+n^bac...+n^cab...=pabc...$$

First suppose $n\ne1$. Then $n^a$ is a factor of $pabc...$ and so $n^a$ is a factor of $p$. Therefore $n=p,a=1$. Then $\frac{n^a}{a}=p$ and so there is no solution.

So $n=1$ and the problem is to find all integer solutions of 
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c } + . . .=p.$$